# Temporary disable clients gtag (Google Analytics) with Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, gtag.js

I want to be able to install a Wordpress plugin on a clients install.

They have a gtag in the `<head>` section. I'd like to disable that one on this specific page to be able to give better information with my settings in the plugin.

I want their script to be in the head but not log page views. Instead my script will do that and deliver to same UA-ID.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common gtag.js look something like this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TRACKING ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'TRACKING ID');
</script>
```

What you need to do for that page is to modify the `gtag('config')`  to

```
gtag('config', 'TRACKING ID', { 'send_page_view': false });
```

Then using your plugin's code, send the pageview:

```
gtag('config', 'TRACKING ID', {'page_path': '/my-page.html'});
```

Comment: Yes, I know but it is the same travking ID I want to deliver the statistics for.

Comment: The first config only tells the tracking code to not send the pageview. You can either remove that from the head section or use the piece I provided. Then in your plugin you will fire the code with the path you want to track.

Comment: Worked great if I edited the tag in the header.php, but on the customer wordpress I won't be able to login on the server and adjust code in .php files. Somehow i need to remove clients GA-tag on this specific page and inject the code you gave as example, because it worked great with manual change.